# Functionality of state is destroyed by another state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, state

**Functionality of the code and the problem**

In the useEffect hook I added to the div of className imageContainer onClick function which whenever is used triggers saveStyle function. The goal of saveStyle function is changing styles of elements and adding to existing array state URLs of images. Without any reason setImages hook doesn't save URLs.

**My attemptions to solve this problem:**

I tried to wait for a little bit because of asynchronous nature of state for example using setTimeout but it didn't work.

I also found out that whenever I delete setting of state which is called particularData and transform a little bit code ( adding manually images with particular source code in div with id dataDisplay  ) then functionality of saveStyle functions works perfectly.

Is there any possibility that one state can block another state? I searched about it and all I found out was that one state can be overloaded with too much data and it can block functionality of another state, but I edited data which is passed to first state (particularData) as much as I can just to not block second state (images) but it also didn't work.

```
const DataDisplay = (props) =>  {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [particularData, setParticularData] = useState([]);

    const saveStyle = (element) => {
        
        const parentOfElement = element.target.parentNode;
        const image = parentOfElement.children[0];

        image.style.animation = "rotation 1s forwards";

        const backgroundDiv = parentOfElement.children[1];

        backgroundDiv.style.animation = "disappear 1s forwards";

        const questionMark = parentOfElement.children[2];

        questionMark.style.animation = "disappear 0.2s forwards";
        setImages([...images, image.src]);
        checkSimilarity();
    }

    const checkSimilarity = () => {
        console.log(images);
    }


    useEffect(() => {

        const dataArray = [...props.data, ...props.data];
        
        const preparedData = dataArray.map((item, index) => {
            return ( <div className="imageContainer" onClick={(element) => saveStyle(element)}>
                        <img className="photo photographyPart" alt={item.alt} src={item.link}></img>
                        <div className="backgroundDiv photographyPart"></div>
                        <img className="askSign photographyPart" src={sign} alt="Question mark" ></img>
                    </div> )
        });
        console.log(preparedData);
        setParticularData(preparedData);
    }, [ props ]);

    return (
        <div id="container">
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="left-side"></div>
            <div id="dataDisplay">{particularData}</div>
            <div id="right-side"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your dependency `[props]` on useEffect is not a good idea.

Comment: Why isn't it good idea. I use it because I need to rerender my component whenever data from asynchronous request from upper component arrive. Is there better approach for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(images);` in saveStyle isn't going to notice the change as setImages will queue an update to be run after saveStyle finishes. If you move `console.log(images);` out of saveStyle into the main part of DataDisplay you should better be able to see what's going on.

images in saveStyle may be a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)  if so, you might be able to fix it by using a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for the set images call.

e.g.

```
setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, image.src]);
```

```js
const DataDisplay = (props) =>  {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
  const [particularData, setParticularData] = React.useState([]);
  
  console.log(images);
  
  const saveStyle = (element) => {
    const parentOfElement = element.target.parentNode;
    const image = parentOfElement.children[0];

    image.style.animation = "rotation 1s forwards";

    const backgroundDiv = parentOfElement.children[1];

    backgroundDiv.style.animation = "disappear 1s forwards";

    const questionMark = parentOfElement.children[2];

    questionMark.style.animation = "disappear 0.2s forwards";
    setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, image.src]);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const dataArray = [...props.data];

    const preparedData = dataArray.map((item, index) => {
      return ( <div key={item.src} className="imageContainer" onClick={(element) => saveStyle(element)}>
        <img className="photo photographyPart" alt={item.alt} src={item.link}></img>
        <div className="backgroundDiv photographyPart"></div>
        <img className="askSign photographyPart" src={item.src} alt="Question mark" ></img>
      </div> );
    });
    // console.log(preparedData);
    setParticularData(preparedData);
  }, [ props ]);

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <div id="top"></div>
      <div id="left-side"></div>
      <div id="dataDisplay">{particularData}</div>
      <div id="right-side"></div>
      <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return <DataDisplay
    data={[
      { alt: 'a', link: '#1', src: 'src1' },
      { alt: 'b', link: '#2', src: 'src2' },
      { alt: 'c', link: '#3', src: 'src3' },
    ]}
  />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't mention it but I tried it and it didn't work. I know that there is a chance that I will not see results because console.log is placed inside saveStyle function but the problem is that when I call it second, third, fourth time it also doesn't show any state changes.

Comment: @BqZz Please see my edit, with the two changes I mentioned, it looks like the state is being updated.

Comment: It works but can you explain me why it didn't console.log value of images array when I was calling it inside saveStyle function?

Comment: @BqZz I think I've mentioned the two important factors in my answer. The most important being the stale closure, I recommend reading up on this, if you haven't already. But basically the version of the images variable that the saveStyle function sees is locked to the state that it had when that function was created. (I think). Which in this case is always `[]`.